# Referencing Environment Variable in Serverless.yml File from jenkinsfile

Tags: amazon-web-services, jenkins, lambda, environment-variables, serverless

I am trying to reference variables that are set in my jenkinsfile in my serverless.yml file.

In jenkinsfile i have this

```
environment {
   HELLO = 'hello-world'
 }
```

In serverless.yml file i have this

```
custom:
  secret: ${env:HELLO}
```

When running jenkins pipeline i get this error

```
A valid environment variable to satisfy the declaration 'env:HELLO' could not be found.
```

Here is my full jenkins file as requested, end goal i want to use val1 and val2 and env variables but if i can figure out how to to with hello world it is the same thing.

```
import com.lmig.intl.cloud.jenkins.exception.BuildException

def getJobName() {
   return env.JOB_NAME
}

environment {
   HELLO = 'hello-world'

 }

def getEnvironment() {

   def jobName = getJobName().split('/')
   def environment = jobName[1].toLowerCase()
   return environment.toLowerCase()
}

node('linux'){

  stage('Checkout'){
      checkout scm
  }
  stage('Pull Secrets From Vault'){
     withAWS(credentials:'aws-cred'){
        def secret = vaultPullSecrets(app:"sls-auxiliary-service",appenv:"nonprod",runtime:'nonprod',keys:'["saslusername","saslpassword"]')
        def val1 = new groovy.json.JsonSlurper().parseText(secret)[0].SASLUSERNAME
        def val2 = new groovy.json.JsonSlurper().parseText(secret)[1].SASLPASSWORD
        if(val1 != '' && val2 != ''){
            echo "Vault Secret pulled Successfully"
        }else{
            echo "Vault Secret Not Found"
            throw new BuildException("Vault Secret Not Found")
        }
     }
  }
  stage('Deploy') {
        def ENVIRONMENT = getEnvironment().replaceAll("\\_","")
        withAWS(credentials:'aws-cred') {
             sh 'npm i serverless-python-requirements'
             sh 'npm install --save-dev serverless-step-functions'
             sh 'npm install serverless-deployment-bucket --save-dev'
             sh 'npm i serverless-pseudo-parameters'
             sh 'npm i serverless-plugin-resource-tagging'
             sh 'pip3 install --user -r requirements.txt'
             sh "serverless deploy --stage ${ENVIRONMENT}"
        }
  }

}
```

Comment: Please share your Jenkinsfile. We need to know the yaml file is already existed in  your source code or created during job running.

Comment: @yong Added the jenkins file, the serverless.yml file exists in my source code already if that it what you mean?

Comment: Sorry @yong that was something i was messing around with you can ignore that, didn't realise i still had it in the code, question is edited now. it should be just a string i am trying to reference

Comment: sorry, I made mistake.

Comment: Any ideas on how to access it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `sed` to replace the placeholder: `${env:HELLO}`to real value, if you can make jenkin job always be executed on Linux slave.

```
stage('Pull Secrets From Vault'){
  withAWS(credentials:'aws-cred'){
    def secret = vaultPullSecrets(app:"sls-auxiliary-service",appenv:"nonprod",runtime:'nonprod',keys:'["saslusername","saslpassword"]')
    def val1 = new groovy.json.JsonSlurper().parseText(secret)[0].SASLUSERNAME

    sh """
      sed -i 's/\${env:HELLO}/${val1}/' <relative path to>/serverless.yml
    """
```

I did a quick practice with a simple pipeline as following, the `sed` command I give work well.

```
node('docker') {

 stage('A') {
    sh '''
        set +x
        echo 'custom:' > serverless.yml
        echo '  secret: ${env:HELLO}' >> serverless.yml
        echo '### Before replace ###'
        cat serverless.yml
    '''

    def val1 = 'hello'

    sh """
        set +x
        sed -i 's/\${env:HELLO}/${val1}/' ./serverless.yml
        echo '### After replace ###'
        cat serverless.yml
    """

 }

}
```

Output of job build

```
[script-pipeline-practice] Running shell script
+ set +x
### Before replace ###
custom:
  secret: ${env:HELLO}
[Pipeline] sh
[script-pipeline-practice] Running shell script
+ set +x
### After replace ###
custom:
  secret: hello
```

Comment: Trying that now, would i just do that from my deploy stage then?

Comment: I don't know where you will use this yaml file in your Jenkinsfile, therefore just complete the replacement before you use it.

Comment: keep getting 'null' values are not allowed in templates when trying to deploy

Comment: If your local machine is Linux or MacOS, can you enter the folder where the yaml insides and  try execute cmd `export HELLO=yyyyy;cat serverless.yml | sed 's/${env:HELLO}/'${HELLO}'/'`, then check the output to see replaced or not.  I can succeed on my local Mac.  if your local machine is Windows, you can try the cmd in Git Bash if you install Git on Windows.

Comment: Ok that worked, but I am having an issue, I want to export the value of my val1 variable and make this the value of ${env:HELLO}.

Comment: but it just gives it makes HELLO = 'val1' rather than the password i have pulled from vault, have you any idea how i could do this?

Comment: Pretty sure I tried that and it didn't work but I will try again tomorrow morning and accept your answer, thanks a lot

Comment: copied and pasted your code but I am getting and the output seems the same but then the build fails and give me the error "service" property is missing in serverless.yml